# How to use superscript HTML code with radio button label with AUI

Tags: html, radio-button, superscript, liferay-aui

How to use superscript external HTML code with radio button label along with AUI

```
<aui:input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio" label="Radio Button"></aui:input>
```

tried with implementing label, but it's not acceptable.

```
    <aui:input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio" label="Radio Button <sup>15</sup>"></aui:input>
```

needs to code dynamically.

Comment: What _specifically_ are you trying to accomplish/having problems with?

Comment: solution with label <sup> tag is not acceptable, how to set with AUI with dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LifeRay code

```
<aui:input cssClass="radio-btn" type="radio" name="radio" value="radio" label="Radio Button"></aui:input>
```

AUI Script

```
AUI().use('aui-autocomplete', function(A) {
        A.one('.radio-btn label').append("<sup>15</sup>"); });
```